# Salt - Multi master of masters

Tags: salt-stack

I modified my salt architecture from one salt master to multiple salt-master/syndic.

I set a high level master of masters where syndics are connected, via `syndic_master`.
It works well, when I run `salt '*' test.ping`, minions from differents masters are returned.

Now I would like to add a second master of masters, my syndic config is now like that

```
id: salt-syndic1
syndic_master:
  - 10.30.2.37
  - 10.30.2.38
```

If I now run `salt '*' test.ping` on both master of masters, returns seems to be split, a mom returns minions from one syndic and the other from other syndic. For minions which did not respond to each not, I get this error :

```
    Minion did not return. [No response]
    The minions may not have all finished running and any remaining minions will return upon completion. To look up the return data for this job later, run the following command:
    
    salt-run jobs.lookup_jid 20201119145521842618
```

So we can see that command is well sent to all minions from both mom, but just one syndic returns result per mom.

I set `master_id` configs only on master of masters servers.

I also test to share jobs cache between moms without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your syndic config

```
syndic_forward_all_events: True
```

Ref: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#syndic-forward-all-events